# Union of a sphere and a diameter.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Im doing a question from the textbook Algebraic Topology by Hatcher, and its starts off by saying 'consider a space $X \subset R^3$ that is the union of a sphere and a diameter'. I'm confused by what this means. In my mind I have a picture of a 2-sphere with a line segment inside it going from one end to the other, with this line segment being the length of the diameter? Is that wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that it is exactly what you describe.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou for the confirmation!